# ListView search NullPointerException - Android

Tags: java, android, listview, search, nullpointerexception

I made an app it a sort of a dictionary translating words
the fragment contains two listviews and an editText which works like a search box
I want to make the search but it always says NullPointer Exception

ListViews Code :

```
public void InitEng(){
    English = new String[]
            {
                    "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5",        
            };
    English_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(English));
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.engword, English_list));
}

public void InitGer(){
    German = new String[]
            {
                   "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", 
            };
    German_list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(German));
    lvn.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lvn.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.gerword, German_list));
}
```

Now the OnTextChanged (where the search is supposed to happen)

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                /** When user changed the Text */
                cs = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                if(SelectEng.isChecked()){
                    try{
                        if("".equals(cs.toString())){
                            InitEng();
                            InitGer();
                        }
                        else{

                            for(String Items: English){
                                if(Items.contains(cs)){
                                    English_list.remove(Items != cs);
                                    lvn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            "found-en",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            adapterE.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            adapterN.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error : "+e,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else if(SelectGer.isChecked()){
                    try{
                        if("".equals(cs.toString())){
                            InitEng();
                            InitGer();
                            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            lvn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else{

                            for(String Items: German){
                                if(Items.contains(cs)){
                                    German_list.remove(Items != cs);
                                    lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            "found-de",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
                                }
                            }
                            adapterN.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            adapterE.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Error : "+e,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The ending result should be :
The list is filtered according to user input
The filter should apply to both lists and show the words facing each other
and I have two listviews so I used 2 adapters
Main problem : NullPointerException
Don't forget that I am working with fragments

Comment: where exactly is the Nullpointer happening? on which object???

Comment: in the "Try()... catch()" part

Comment: I just remembered that the Log says the NullPointer Exception happens in "PerformSearchEng()" function

Comment: you dont need to remember so hard... run the code again and copy the logcat output here.... :)

Comment: I made some major changes please take time to evaluate my work, I am still new to dealing with lists and adapters

Answer (score 0):

In your `performAction()` you set

```
cs = null;
```

and call

```
cs.toString().equals(..)
```

which of course produce a NullPointerException, because you set cs to null. You catch this exception, but i guess so your `InitGer()` is never called, and your Variable `English` is null too and causes uncatched NullPointerException in `performSearchEng()`. 
So you have to think about this line:

```
CharSequence cs = null;
```

(Btw: by convention you should start variable names and functions with lower case, while upper case are for class names)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: if you want to search a word from an edittext, you have to get it from the view. I dont see that in your code. Change cs to a string and instead of cs=null do in your Fragment something like private EditText ed; in OnCreate: ed = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idofyourEditText), and in performAction String cs = ed.getText().toString();

Comment: I tried that several times and it didn't work, I deleted the submit button and I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing but with "OnTextChanged" instead of a button click

Comment: maybe we can help you if you post the full code of your fragment and your xml files

Comment: please take time to evaluate the changes, I am new to dealing with lists and adapters, I made some major changes; thanks in advance